# Mupad cast boolean to integer

Tags: matlab, mupad

I give a simple example of what I want to do in Matlabs MuPad

```
S := matrix([[0,S_1,S_2]]);
sum(S[k]*(k < 2)* S[k] * (TRUE), k=1..3)
```

should be: "S_1^2 + S_2"
however I get: `Error: The first argument must be of type 'Type::Arithmetical'. [sum]`

I understand the error, I just don't know how to succeed.
Advice appreciated. I'm looking for some kind of indicator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question:

[image]

Start with the inner term. To have a valid number 0 or 1, I used the following expression:

```
piecewise([A[k]>a*B[l],1],[Otherwise,0])
```

The rest is straight forward:

```
sum(sum(A[k]*B[l]*piecewise([A[k]>a*B[l],1],[Otherwise,0]), l=1..L), k=1..K)
```

Comment: It seems a bit bulky but it actually works. Is there a way to shorten the input by maybe defining a procedure? I tried but it lacked the ability described in the next sentence. Your solution even distinguishes all possible cases if the logical expressions cannot be evaluated to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

```
S := matrix([[0,S_1,S_2]]);

sum(S[k]^(4-k), k=1..3)
```

I'm to really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have some formula of the form \sum_{k=0}^K\sum_{l=0}^L [A_k*B_l * (A_k > \alpha B_l)] and I'm trying to expand the sum by a CAS rather than doing it by hand for various \alpha and various L,K, A_k, B_l. The inequation should yield 1 if the statement is true and 0 otherwise. Of course it is obvious what to do for a given set of parameters, however because of that a machine can do it. This is the motivation behind this. Maybe you can help me with another approach.

Comment: The `* (A_k > \alpha B_l)` part is strictly speaking invalid, because a boolean expression is multiplied with a number. But it's obvious what is intended, I'll write a new answer.